# Format button text and images in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to format text and the image like the image attached.
How can I center the text and put the image with a little padding on the left side to the side?

```
<Button StyleClass="btnFAF" Text="Field Activity" Image="icon.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnFAF" Clicked="btnFAF_Clicked" BorderRadius="6">
    <Button.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="OpenSans-Regular.ttf#OpenSans-Regular"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.FontFamily>
</Button>
```

[Format I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwRt.jpg)

Comment: instead of a button, I would just compose the layout you want using a Layout control and attach a TapGestureRecognizer to it

Comment: @Jason how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of a button, I would just compose the layout you want using a Layout control and attach a TapGestureRecognizer to it

I'll illustrate with nested StackLayouts, but this may be better suited to using a Grid instead

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MyTappedHandler" />
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
  <Image ... />
  <StackLayout>
    <Label ... />
    <Label ... />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```